# Is JBOD or striping better for lots of small files?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, raid, io

I have a server in multi-disk configuration using *LVM-on-LUKS* in JBOD mode. But I notice in `htop` that the kernel time in CPU usage is (un)usually very high, and in `iotop` the *jbd2/dm-5-8* and *dmcrypt_write/2* processes frequently take the majority of the IO%

I checked with `fio` and realized that the 4K random IOPS is also far below the value for each drive, let alone the whole set of LVM disks. I thought that when adding more disks to the JBOD set then LVM can deliver accesses to individual disks in parallel, so for example I'm having 4 SSD drives at 600k IOPS each then it should be able to achieve ~4×600k IOPS, but it seems that's not the case

So I'm trying to do some tuning, possibly by rebuilding the drive set from scratch. Since the server is supposed to deal with lots of small files ~40-80KB on average, I think JBOD should be better, because even the default RAID0 stripe size is larger than the files themselves. Besides if running in RAID0 mode then every time a small file is read/write then all the stripes in the all the drives would be unnecessarily accessed

Is my understanding correct? How can I improve IOPS in this case? Would changing to Btrfs or ZFS and remove the LVM layer help?

Answer (score 0):

Update - My initial answer is still useful, but on rereading I see you are using SSD's.  This makrs me think you are looking in the wrong place.  I posit that what is slowing you down is the encryption/decryption of your data.  Maybe you can look to moving that to be done in the SSD firmware.

Initial answer -

I would expect RAID0 to give you better performance then JBOD as it greatly increases the chance that files will be on different disks which will speed up reads.

(Assume for a moment the array was 5 same size disks, and 1/5th full and not fragmented - the data would be spread over 5 disks  for RAUD0, but all on 1 disk in JBOD. Even if the disk was full (but reasonably nrw) - all the latest files would be on 1 disk - so operations only looking at the latest files would again be on only 1 disk with JBOD)

If files in the same sector/disk block there is still no benefit to jbod over RAID0.  JBODS advantages are its ability to use different size disks, the ability to partially recover data and increase disk space more easily.

Comment: yes I was already looking into using the SSD's hardware encryption feature. But I still have concern about RAID0, because most of the files won't fit in a single stripe in a single disk, so reading all the disks to read that file would be slower

Comment: I do not believe your assertion about reading the disks is correct. The whole idea is that if files don't fit in a single stripe RAID speeds up the read/write by parallelizing it.

Comment: A bit of Googling - https://www.pcworld.com/article/439925/feed-your-greed-for-speed-by-installing-ssds-in-raid-0.html shows that the speed increase for small files holds true on SSD (as well as large files and HDD.)